# Count filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba

Excel - VBA
I want to count how many rows there are after filtering the table.
How do I do this? 
I have tried `rows_count = Range("AX:AX").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count`
but that gives me full number of rows there are in Excel 2010.

Answer (score 4):

Once you've applied your filter, just use something like this:

```
rows_count = Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
```

---

For example, I filled `A2:C20` with `=RAND()` and used the following code:

```
Sub filter()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1:C20")

    sht.AutoFilterMode = False
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<0.5"

    MsgBox sht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to that you're referring to the entire column instead of just your table. Try with

```
rows_count = Range(cells(1,"AX"), cells(cells(rows.count,"AX").end(xlup).row,"AX")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
```

It would be better to declare which sheet you're referrring to so use

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    rows_count = Range(.Cells(1, "AX"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "AX").End(xlUp).Row, "AX")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
End With
```

Where `Sheet1` is the name of your sheet you're referring to.

Or if you're using a table object you can get your answer with

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1)
    rows_count = .ListColumns(Columns("AX").Column).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
End With
```